# Not In operator eliminates NULL values rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to retrieve all rows with values except 1,2,3,4,5 in my COLUMNA in TABLEA .

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE COLUMNA NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

But this eliminates the rows with NULL values in COLUMNA too.

I don't want to eliminate NULL values rows and would like to include those rows in the resultset.

Alternatively, I can try below query for the same

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE COLUMNA NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR COLUMNA  IS NULL.
```

But I would like to know, why is it necessary to add this OR condition?

Comment: You can read about sql three valued logic at https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic

Answer (score 6):

Why is the additional necessary?

`NULL` comparisons almost always results in `NULL`, rather than true or false.  A `WHERE` clause filters out all non-true values, so they get filtered out.

This is how SQL defines `NULL`.  Why is `NULL` defined like this?

`NULL` does not mean "missing" in SQL.  It means "unknown".  So, the result of `<unknown> not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is "unknown", because the value could be 1 or it might be 0.  Hence it gets filtered.

I will also note that the SQL standard includes `NULL`-safe comparisons, `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` and `IS DISTINCT FROM` corresponding to `=` and `<>` respectively.  These treat `NULL` as just "any other value", so two `NULL` values are considered equal.  However, there is no construct for `NULL`-safe `IN` and `NOT IN`, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE ISNULL(COLUMNA,0) NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)